# Unable to retrieve using a tag

Tags: svn, tags

We are trying to automate using visual studio an application that will:

1. create a copy of the trunk at a spcific time point.
2. Assign a tag to the directory
3. Remove the directory
4. Be able to recreate only the tagged directory in the future

To do this we do a svn copy  giving it a tag name, i.e.

```
svn copy "C:\SVN_Checkout\P41-ships\complete" "C:\SVN_Checkout\P41-ships V1.1"
```

We commit the changes using `svn commit`. At this point we can checkout the V1.1 tagged directory no problems.

We delete the directory using `svn delete "C:\SVN_Checkout\P41-ships V1.1"`

But when we go to retrieve the tagged directory we get an error
`URL 'SVN_Checkout\P41-ships%20V%201.1' doesn't exist`.

What are we doing wrong or can this even be done?

Comment: So you create the tag, then delete the tag, and then are puzzled by the fact that the tag no longer exists?

Answer (score 0):

> We delete the directory using `svn delete "C:\SVN_Checkout\P41-ships V1.1"`
>
> But when we go to retrieve the tagged directory we get an error
>   `URL 'SVN_Checkout\P41-ships%20V%201.1' doesn't exist`.

There's no "but". Once you `svn delete` the branch, it's no longer existing. That is what deletion is for, after all. (Of course, SVN does preserve history, so it's still there in older revisions. But not in the current one.)

Could it be that what you want is a *file-level* delete? That would be
`del "C:\SVN_Checkout\P41-ships V1.1"`

Comment: What we are trying to do is to remove the SVN tag directory so that when a checkout is done at the trunk level the revision information does not get displayed. Maybe I need to change the SVN directory structure to be.  Trunk/top level and trunk/revision and only let developers checkout from the trunk/top level

Comment: @user1156529: "What we are trying to do is to remove the SVN tag directory so that when a checkout is done at the trunk level the revision information does not get displayed." I have no idea what that means.

Comment: It means that when I do a checkout at the truck level the P41-ships V1.1 directory does not get checkout on the local copy.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is delete the checked out code, just use *normal* delete methods, not `svn delete`. The `svn` commands apply the changes to the repository, not *just* the local filesystem.